# How to create Discriminator column in Database First

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a Database First approach to my application and Entity Framework.  I have a base class that many other classes inherit.  I am trying to save the class to my EF database, however, I keep getting an error that there is no Discriminator column.

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'Discriminator'.

Since I am using Database First, how do I manually create this column in my table?  I cannot seem to find the datatype of it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The entity framework would try to check for the column in all of the derived classes (isn't that what inheritance is all about?). You can try adding `[NotMapped]` attribute to your child classes.

```
[NotMapped]
public class ChildClass : ParentClass {
    // other stuff here
}
```

This would minimize your problem. This attribute tells Entity framework which of the properties (*if applied to fields*) or classes do not need to be mapped. Read more about it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#NotMapped

Comment: Thanks Afzaal.  However, do you know if it is possible to instruct all children to not be mapped so that I don't have to put `[NotMapped]` at the top of each?

Comment: @gnychis, then put it on the top of the class.